# Developing a class Method

Tags: python

I am having trouble with this question about developing a class. Here is the problem:
Develop a class myList that is a subclass of the built-in list class. The only different between myList and list is that the sort method is overrridden.myList containers should behave just like regular lists, except in this case:

```
   >>>x = myList([1, 2, 3, ])
   >>>x
   [1,2,3]
   >>>x.reverse()
   >>>x
   >>>[3,2,1]
   >>> x[2]
   1
   >>>x.sort()
   You wish...
```

I am familiar with the basics of classes, but since this is an online course, there I am having a hard time figuring a lot of these things that to some may seem basic but for a first time person on Python, is pretty difficult.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem with your attempt, or just having trouble getting started?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html this should help you out.  specifically, check out section 9.5 (Inheritance)

Comment: What is "this case"? The list is exactly `[3,2,1]`? You've called `reverse` on the list at some point? It's sorted in reverse order? You've accessed the element at index 2?

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking through youtube videos on classes and they all assume that the watcher has some previous python experience so it didn't really help. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @CammyGirl, if you're a python beginner I highly recommend ditching this course and working through the [python tutorial.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) Your course is not teaching you what you need to know about python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To develop a subclass you just do this:

```
class myList(list):
    pass
```

To override a method, it's just this:

```
class myList(list):
    def sort(self):
        pass
```

To override a method and have it behave exactly like the base class except under a certain condition, do this:

```
class myList(list)
    def sort(self):
        if whatever_the_condition_is:
            print('You wish...')
        else:
            super().sort()
```

So, now you just have to put the right expression in for `whatever_the_condition_is`.

You didn't explain that in your question, but I'm guessing the condition is "the listed is sorted exactly backward". So, that'll be the fun part of the assignment. Try to write the code that gets an `is_sorted_backward` value out of `self`, and, if you get stuck, ask for help.

Comment: Since this is homework, it is probably not a good idea to just explicitly give the code for the answer. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: @Asad: I _think_ the actual homework is to implement that `whatever_the_condition_is` part, so giving him enough of a skeleton to get to that point is helpful. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps. Let's see if the OP responds to your comment.

Comment: Don't know if this is worth it, but you could also mention how overriding in old-style classes works, since that seems to be the topic the OP is covering.

Comment: @Asad Why do you figure old-style classes are implicated?

Comment: @Marcin They're probably not. I meant overriding in inheritance seems to be the topic the OP is covering, and it can't hurt to explain the difference between how this used to work in old versions of Python and how it works now.

Comment: @Asad I'm not sure it's worth it. That opens a whole can of worms that novices don't need to look in.

Comment: Thank you, yes this is a great "skeleton" for what I need. I think I know how to do it, someone gave me a link here too that also cleared up a lot so I can go from here.

Comment: `super().sort()` needs to be `super(myList, self).sort()` in python 2

Comment: @Asad: Pre-new-style classes, you _can't_ inherit from builtins like `list`. With new-style classes, you can, and it's always a new-style class. So old-style class inheritance can't be relevant.

Comment: @Eric: Yes, it does. Whether that's relevant or not depends on which version the OP is using. Since she didn't say, and everything in her sample code is exactly the same in 2.x and 3.x, I'll just +1 your comment and leave it as-is, without incorporating it into the answer.

Answer (score -2):

One can inherit build-in classes and override some methods. 
But it is important to support existing functionality (if You don't reimplement it from the scratch).

One can run parent's method two ways

Using `super()` function

```
class MyList(list):
    def sort(self):
        print ("I am goung to sort this heap of data...")
        res = super(MyList, self).sort()
        print ("I have done this!!!")
        return res    # I think it is good practice to return parent result 
                      # (if You don't plan to return Your own result)
```

Run parent's unbound method and pas self as first argument (You should understand that this is exactly what You need otherwise use `super`)

```
class MyList(list):
    def sort(self):
        print ("I am goung to sort this heap of data...")
        res = list.sort(self)
        print ("I have done this!!!")
        return res    # I think it is good practice to return parent result 
                      # (if You don't plan to return Your own result)
```

My examples work with python 2.x for python 3.x `super` syntax will be different but main idea remain the same.

Comment: -1 This guy probably learned nothing because you just gave him the whole code and no explanation.

Comment: @Marcin This is tangential, but I would wager the OP isn't a guy.

Comment: @Asad Fair enough. It was just a numbers handle when I posted that.

Comment: Guys You are right. I have done mistake but I thought that my post will be considered as continue of abarnet's one. This is the reason.